# La galería queda por detrás del menú

Tags: javascript, html, css

En el siguiente código presento la particularidad de que mi galería está por detrás del menú que realice, quisiera de ante mano si me pudieran colaborar con este código por favor, ya que es para un proyecto familiar que necesito entregar, muchísimas gracias a todos.

Código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Sub-menu Responsive</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font2/flaticon.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
       <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
        <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Quiénes Somos<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gobierno Corporativo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transparencia Social</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Actividades</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Oportunidades<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Programa Plan Padrino</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Programa de Voluntariado</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donaciones</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CAMPUS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="img2/img1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <section class="caption">
                    <h2>Lorem slider #1</h2>
                </section>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class>1</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
            <li class="flex-nav-prev">
                <a class="flex-prev" href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex-nav-next">
                <a class="flex-next" href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Código de estilos css

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #01A9DB;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn-menu {
    display: none;
}

header label {
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #01A9DB;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color:aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background: #AF7AC5;
}

.menu a span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    header label {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 70%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .menu ul {
        display: block;
        background: #01A9DB;
    }

    .menu ul li:hover ul {
        display: none;
        position: static;
    }

    .menu a span {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
    }

    #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    .menu ul ul {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    .menu ul ul a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
    }
}
```

Codigo menu.js

```
$(".submenu").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
});

$("ul").click(function(p){
    p.stopPropagation();
});
```

Código flexslider css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("../fonts2/Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("../fonts2/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../fonts2/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts2/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts2/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #5f2c82;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
}

.flexslider {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;

    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.70);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    position: relative;
}

.slides,
.slides li,
.slides li img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slides li {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    background: #1A89DF;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80);

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;

    list-style: none;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: -29px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.flex-control-nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}

.flex-control-nav li a.flex-active {
    background: #353535;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
    z-index: 3;
    list-style: none;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #1A89DF;
    color: aliceblue;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80);

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-direction-nav a::before {
  content: "\f102";
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next::before {
    content: "\f11c";
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: 0px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: 0px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 15px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 15px;
}

.caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.caption h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(000,000,000,0.70);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .flex-direction-nav a {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
        left: 15px;
    }

    .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
        right: 15pxactive;
    }

    .caption h2 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .caption h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .flexslider {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: none;
    }

    .slides li {
        overflow: hidden; 
    }

    .slides li img {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .flex-direction-nav a {
        top: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .slides li img {
        transform: translateX(-90px);
    }
}
```

Código main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        pauseOnAction: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 3000,
        touch: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Organiza mejor el código que tienes para ayudarte mejor. Usa el comando **'control + M'**.

Comment: seria mejor probar tu pagina, existe una web llamada `codepen` si subes el código, podremos manipular el código.

Comment: edita tu codito o permite que los usuarios lo editen para poder entender que pasa o coloca el archivo html

Comment: Sube tu código a una cuenta de https://codepen.io/ o bien utiliza la herramienta integrada para subir código (dejo imagen). [![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j62n6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j62n6.png)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#enviar_add_evento').on('click', function() {
   alert($('input[name=tipo]:checked').val()); 
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #01A9DB;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn-menu {
    display: none;
}

header label {
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #01A9DB;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    z-index:100;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color:aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background: #AF7AC5;
}

.menu a span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    header label {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 70%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .menu ul {
        display: block;
        background: #01A9DB;
    }

    .menu ul li:hover ul {
        display: none;
        position: static;
    }

    .menu a span {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
    }

    #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    .menu ul ul {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    .menu ul ul a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
    }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("../fonts2/Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("../fonts2/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../fonts2/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts2/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts2/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #5f2c82;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
}

.flexslider {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;

    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.70);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    position: relative;
}

.slides,
.slides li,
.slides li img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slides li {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    background: #1A89DF;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80);

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;

    list-style: none;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: -29px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.flex-control-nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}

.flex-control-nav li a.flex-active {
    background: #353535;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
    z-index: 3;
    list-style: none;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #1A89DF;
    color: aliceblue;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80);

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-direction-nav a::before {
  content: "\f102";
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next::before {
    content: "\f11c";
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: 0px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: 0px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 15px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 15px;
}

.caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.caption h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(000,000,000,0.70);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .flex-direction-nav a {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
        left: 15px;
    }

    .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
        right: 15pxactive;
    }

    .caption h2 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .caption h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .flexslider {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: none;
    }

    .slides li {
        overflow: hidden; 
    }

    .slides li img {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .flex-direction-nav a {
        top: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .slides li img {
        transform: translateX(-90px);
    }
}
Código main.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        pauseOnAction: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 3000,
        touch: true
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Sub-menu Responsive</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font2/flaticon.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
       <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
        <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Quiénes Somos<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gobierno Corporativo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transparencia Social</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Actividades</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Oportunidades<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Programa Plan Padrino</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Programa de Voluntariado</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donaciones</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CAMPUS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="img2/img1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <section class="caption">
                    <h2>Lorem slider #1</h2>
                </section>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class>1</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
            <li class="flex-nav-prev">
                <a class="flex-prev" href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex-nav-next">
                <a class="flex-next" href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que buscas.

La solución es básica incluir la propiedad `z-index` con un valor mayor a 4 por las capas que tienes, quedaria asi;

```
.menu ul {
    background: #01A9DB;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 4;
}
```